# Disqus API: Pull latest conversations in my blog for a snippet

Tags: comments, disqus

How can I pull the ***latest conversations in my blog*** (the site as a whole) and show perhaps the latest 10 comments as a conversation summary from **Disqus**?

Answer (score 3):

You can build a Most Recent Comments widget using the Disqus forums/listPosts API method. Using a limit of 10 will give you the 10 latest comments on your forum as a whole.

Documentation: http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/details/

Some additional code examples for using the Disqus API can be found here: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/

Answer (score 3):

You can use following scripts to pull latest conversations.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://funbutlearn.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=25&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=40&excerpt_length=200"></script>
```

Just you need to replace your own Disqus name.

If you want to use the combo plugin, then use following script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://funbutlearn.disqus.com/combination_widget.js?num_items=25&hide_mods=0&color=grey&default_tab=recent&excerpt_length=70"></script>
```

You can even add some extra CSS to make them more beautiful.